# Why do I have to destruct and reconstruct the non-generic variant of a generic enum when mapping from one generic to another?

Tags: generics, types, enums, rust, variant

I have a generic enum where only one variant makes use of the generic type.

When “converting” a `ParseResult<T>` to a `ParseResult<U>` the compiler forces me to destruct the non-generic part, too. The non-generic part is immediately reassembled and returned in exactly the same way.

Is there a more elegant solution without the code duplication?

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
enum ParseResult<'a, T> {
    Success(T, &'a str),
    Failure(&'static str),
}

fn char<'a>(c: char) -> impl Fn(&'a str) -> ParseResult<'a, char> {
    move |input| match input.chars().next() {
        Some(candidate) if c == candidate => ParseResult::Success(candidate, &input[1..]),
        Some(_) => ParseResult::Failure("chars didn't match"),
        None => ParseResult::Failure("unexpected end of stream"),
    }
}

fn or<'a, T>(
    mut lhs: impl FnMut(&'a str) -> ParseResult<T>,
    mut rhs: impl FnMut(&'a str) -> ParseResult<T>,
) -> impl FnMut(&'a str) -> ParseResult<T> {
    move |input| match lhs(input) {
        ParseResult::Failure(_) => rhs(input),
        ok => ok,
    }
}

fn and<'a, T, U>(
    mut lhs: impl FnMut(&'a str) -> ParseResult<T>,
    mut rhs: impl FnMut(&'a str) -> ParseResult<U>,
) -> impl FnMut(&'a str) -> ParseResult<(T, U)> {
    move |input| match lhs(input) {
        ParseResult::Success(left, after) => match rhs(after) {
            ParseResult::Success(right, after) => ParseResult::Success((left, right), after),
            // Only explicit works:
            ParseResult::Failure(why) => ParseResult::Failure(why),
        },
        // Same as line as above, same goes here.
        ParseResult::Failure(why) => ParseResult::Failure(why),
    }
}
```

Things that didn't work instead of the two `::Failure` lines towards the end:

1. `bad => bad,` expected tuple, found type parameter `U`
2. `bad => bad as ParseResult<(T, U)>,`
3. `bad @ ParseResult::Failure(why) => bad,` expected tuple, found type parameter `U`

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=31ba9f0c7d4c5a551f4651acd711d998)

Comment: As a side note: Rusts own `Result` already offers methods that you could try. (Of course, that only applies if your problem is related to your `ParseResult` and not to other generic enums.)

Comment: You could have reduced this to a *much* smaller example. Please take some time and  consideration to produce good examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the non-generic part is immediately reassembled and returned in exactly the same way. Isn't there a smarter/more elegant solution without the code duplication?

It looks like it is reassembled the same way, but it isn't because it changed type from `ParseResult<T>` to `ParseResult<U>` (or `ParseResult<(T, U)>` in your case). These have different sizes so `ParseResult<T>::Failed(err)` is not the same as `ParseResult<U>::Failed(err)`.

If we look at [how the standard library handles this problem for `Result::map`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.43.0/src/libcore/result.rs#L517-L522), you can see that the same pattern is used:

```
match self {
     Ok(t) => Ok(op(t)),
     Err(e) => Err(e),
}
```